# apache tomcat creating new instance of sqlite database in java

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, tomcat

I am using an sqlite database in java using [xerial sqlite jdbc driver](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) in order to store some data, 1 connection at a time.
It worked fine until I decided to use Apache tomcat on my server instead of java sockets (used for testing) and I noticed my queries yielded null results despite data being on the database.
I searched this issue and apparently tomcat creates a new instance of this database, which has the same tables but has no data.
I tried moving my database into the resource folder but this did not help.

```
public static Connection getConn() throws SQLException {
      if(c == null){
         c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
      }
      return c;
   }
```

this is how the code connects to the database. I believe moving the database and changing the address should solve the issue but I dont know where to.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the full path to your existing database file in your JDBC URL - so, something like:

```
"jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/your/mysqlite.db"
```

If you are on Windows, then it might look like this:

```
"jdbc:sqlite:C:/path/to/your/mysqlite.db"
```

These are examples of *absolute* paths.

In your case, the database location in your JDBC URL is simply `mysqlite.db`, with no additional path information. This is a *relative* path, because it does not start with a slash or a drive letter.

This means the location of the DB file is relative to the working directory of the Java program (where the program was started). In the case of Tomcat, that is typically the `CATALINA_HOME/bin` directory - where `CATALINA_HOME` is typically the location where Tomcat was installed. (This may vary depending on how Tomcat was installed and launched.)

I would recommend you keep the database file in a separate location from Tomcat.

(SQLite will create a new, empty database in the specified location, if one does not already exist - so it's not Tomcat which is creating it, but rather the SQLite driver).